# Наследование в ООП

Tags: java, c#, ооп

Допустим, есть три класса `А, В, С`. В каждом классе есть одинаковое поле например `int field = 555;` то есть одинаковый тип и имя поля. Класс `В` наследуется от `А`, а `С` наследуется от `В`: A←B←C. Потом я создаю объект класса `С` и у меня есть три одинаковых переменных: две от наследников и моего класса, то есть `int field=555;`

Вопрос: как это работает?
Почему компилятор не ошибается и как он их различает? Не откажусь от ссылки на правильное чтение по ООП. Википедия не помогает.

Comment: @AnderFace подозреваю, что любой адепт ООП за такие фантазии предаст Вас анафеме. Проектировать таким образом иерархию классов? Интересно, зачем? Для маскировки смысла?

Comment: @alexlz, знакомый проходил собеседование и сказал что был такой вопрос : вот допустим есть три класса А, В, С, ....... как это работает и почему !

Comment: @AnderFace

     Страшно далеки они от народа.
               В.И. Ленин. Памяти Герцена.

Увы. Но за такие дизайнерские решения надо карать без всякой жалости.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще это можно определить из контекста. Например:

```
class A
{
    public int Field;
}

class B : A
{
    public int Field;

    public void Foo()
    {          
        // обращение к полю Field класса B
        Field = 12;
        // обращение к полю Field класса-предка с помощью base
        base.Field = 10; 
        Console.WriteLine(base.Field); // 10
        Console.WriteLine(Field);      // 12          
    }
}
```

В C# для такого случая рекомендуется пометить поле/метод/свойство модификатором **new**:

```
public new int Field;
```

А в этом случае все еще проще:

```
class B : A
{        
    public void Foo()
    {            
        Field = 12;
        // base.Field указывает на то же значение, что и просто field, 
        //поскольку Field не переопределен в наследнике
        base.Field = 10; 
        Console.WriteLine(base.Field); // 10
        Console.WriteLine(Field);      // 10
    }
}
```

В С++ это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
class A
{
    public:
        int field;
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
      int field;

    void Foo()
    {            
        field = 12; 
        A::field = 10;           
        cout << A::field << endl; // 10
        cout << field << endl;    // 12
    }
};
```

В Java - не знаю, но наверняка тоже что-то имеется аналогичное.

Comment: в Java:

    public class A { 
      public int field;
    }
    
    public class B extends A {
      public int field;
    
      public void foo() {
        field = 12;
        super.field = 21;
    
        System.out.println(field);
        System.out.println(super.field);
      }
    }

Comment: @Nofate спасибо за дополнение

Comment: @Nofate - как вы в комментарии сделали подсветку и форматирование кода?

Comment: @ua6xh, так же как и в вопросах/ответах - Markdown разметкой.

Comment: отступ в пробела обычно помогает. Хотя для большого кода замучаешься ставить по 4 пробела на каждую строку. Но еще как вариант можно написать в формие ответа, отформатировать, а потом скопировать в форму комментария

Comment: Вроде бы был баг, из-за которого просто код без текста не форматируется (вероятно тримаются leading whitespaces). В таких случаях я первой строкой ставлю точку ).

Comment: public static void // прям как крибле-крабле бумс

Comment: Так её же здесь нет, можно только выделить текст `вот так` - но это будет выделение кода в одну строку, а при нажатии CTRL+K происходит снятие фокуса с textarea...
![][1]

[1]: http://i.imgur.com/5pUe28a.png

Comment: Кого нет-то? Кнопок разметки? Так я [правила разметки](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) в голове неплохо держу )

Comment: @Nofate , @DreamChild - ох эти лайфхаки)